# Is `char* p=0; std::equal(p,p,p)` well-defined according to the C++ standard?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl

Is the following well-defined according to the C++ standard?

```
char* p = 0;
std::equal(p, p, p);
```

The question is really this:

Does the standard require that `std::equal(begin1, end1, begin2)` is implemented in such a way that if `begin1 == end1`, then `begin1` and `begin2` can be any pointer, even one that does not point to a valid memory object?

I assume this is the intention of the standard, but I have not been able to find a statement that makes this clear.

The reason I am concerned about this, is that VisualStudio apparently tries to check the "validity" of `begin2` even when `begin1 == end1`. And that contradicts my understanding of the requirements of the standard.

EDIT: Here is the code from VS 2012 that I believe is in violation of the standard:

```
template<class _InIt1, class _InIt2> inline
bool equal(_InIt1 _First1, _InIt1 _Last1, _InIt2 _First2)
{   // compare [_First1, _Last1) to [First2, ...)
    _DEBUG_RANGE(_First1, _Last1);
    _DEBUG_POINTER(_First2);
    return (_Equal1(_Unchecked(_First1), _Unchecked(_Last1), _First2, _Is_checked(_First2)));
}

template<class _Ty> inline
void _Debug_pointer(const _Ty *_First, _Dbfile_t _File, _Dbline_t _Line)
{   // test iterator for non-singularity, const pointers
    if (_First == 0)
        _DEBUG_ERROR2("invalid null pointer", _File, _Line);
}
```

Comment: I would think that's well-defined.

Comment: @chris I don't think so. The "iterators" are invalid, so it's undefined behaviour. You will have to check p is not null before-hand.

Comment: @NeilKirk: They're not invalid; just not dereferencable. You can still compare `begin1` with `end1`, so the algorithm is well-defined since it will only do that comparison and not try to dereference anything.

Comment: @MikeSeymour An invalid iterator is one which does not point to a valid position in the data structure, or (in the case of arrays) one past the last valid position. Address 0 is neither in a valid data structure nor after one.

Comment: @NeilKirk: A null pointer is a valid pointer, and therefore a valid iterator. It's singular, and not dereferencable, but still comparable with another null pointer, so that `[null,null)` is a valid range.

Comment: @MikeSeymour A valid pointer but not a valid iterator.

Comment: @NeilKirk: I don't know why you say that, or what you think "valid" means in this context. It's a singular iterator (as described by C++11 24.2.1/5), but it compares equal to itself, and is therefore *reachable* from itself (as defined by 24.2.1/6), and therefore forms a valid (empty) *range* with itself (as defined by 24.2.1/7). The only requirement for this function is that the two input ranges are valid; and an empty range formed by two null pointers meets that requirement, whatever Microsoft think.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So we have 25.2.1/1 which says:

> Returns: true if for every iterator i in the range [first1,last1) the
> following corresponding conditions hold: *i == *(first2 + (i -
> first1)), pred(*i, *(first2 + (i - first1))) != false.
>
> Otherwise,
> returns false.

In your case there are no iterators in the range [0, 0) so "every" iterator in the range passes the test, but no actual test should be done (since no iterators exist in the range upon which to test).

It looks like a VisualStudio bug to me.

Comment: The way this is written, it may not be a bug, but a different interpretation.  That is, checking in a range [first, last) implies there is a range.  Since [0, 0) has no elements, it has no range, and thus, is invalid input.

Comment: @Zac Howland No other algorithm has a restriction preventing you from passing in an empty range. Why would this be different?

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour The counterpoint to that would be passing what are "valid" iterators that are *not* convertible. Ex: a container end, i.e. some vector `v.end()`. Passing `std::equal(v.end(), v.end(), p)` had better work. I concur with Mark's answer to this question. This should work, and VS is being rather pedantic.

Comment: @MarkB I don't disagree, I was just playing devil's advocate that it may not be an actual bug, but simply something the standard needs to clarify better.

Comment: @WhozCraig If what you are saying is true, then VS is not just very pedantic, it is in conflict with the standard, right?

Comment: @KristianSpangsege VS has a rich (and sometimes annoying) debug-iterator interface for validating that you know what you are doing. It is conceivable they simply missed this as a possible condition. Without the source immediately at-hand, i couldn't say. If this happens in a *release* build I would be pretty-convinced its a bug.

Comment: @ZacHowland: The standard is quite clear: there's no precondition that the range be non-empty, and the specification here clearly requires it to return `false` if it is empty.

Comment: @MikeSeymour:  It does not state it returns `false` if it is empty.  If it is empty, technically both empty-sets are equal.  It states that if every element in the range is equal, it returns true; otherwise (meaning if an element differs), it returns false.  2 null-sets would be equal.  In fact, the common implementation of `std::equal` would return `true` for null-sets as it would skip over the for-loop and jump directly to `return true`.

Comment: @MikeSeymour I think you meant to say "and the specification here clearly requires it to return **`true`** if it is empty" - as Mike also points out. Could you confirm that?

Comment: @ZacHowland: Yes, sorry, I wrote `false` when I meant `true`. My point is that it's well-defined for any valid input range, including an empty range like this one.

Comment: @MikeSeymour As I said earlier, I don't really disagree, but playing devil's advocate is no longer necessary with his update as he is doing this in a debug build with the iterator debug level set to its default.

Answer (score 2):

As @Zac pointed out, this check is Visual Studio being extra pedantic in the name of security. If you want Visual Studio to more closely comply with the standard even in debug builds, you can turn off this behaviour by setting the macro [_ITERATOR_DEBUG_LEVEL to 0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh697468.aspx).

Comment: I don't doubt that what you are saying is true, and I know that VS has a tradition of not adhering strictly to the standard, but is improving. Still, it is inappropriate to enable debug features by default that conflict with the standard. I hope they will eventually get around to fixing this.

Comment: @KristianSpangsege I see what you're saying but I wouldn't hold my breath. I would guess that their desire to have more hacker resistant windows software outweighs potential annoyances such as these, especially when they provide a mechanism to turn it off.

Answer (score 0):

With your update, It is clear that it is not a violation of the standard, but a debugging check.  If you compile it in Release mode, those checks do not get run, and the function matches the standard's description.

It is useful to have that information in Debug mode as it will help you to track down some hard to find bugs.

Comment: I don't agree. They check too much. This gets in the way of perfectly correct and sane code. They could easily modify their debugging facility such that it would comply with the standard and still catch null pointers when the range is not empty. I'm pretty sure it it is either just a bug, or a "thinko". From and algebraic point of view (and, I believe, from the point of view of the standard,) there is nothing wrong or buggy about passing undereferenceable pointers as part of an empty range.

Comment: It is only a warning:  `Warning 1 warning C4996: 'std::_Equal1': Function call with parameters that may be unsafe - this call relies on the caller to check that the passed values are correct. To disable this warning, use -D_SCL_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See documentation on how to use Visual C++ 'Checked Iterators'` and a debug assertion (which you can disable).

Comment: It is still wrong and inappropriate in my opinion, assuming that I interpret the standard correctly.

Comment: The standard does not entirely apply to a debug build.  Debuggers do all sorts of tricks to help find/prevent/point-out potential pitfalls that are hard (if not impossible) to track down in a release build (that the standards to apply to).  If the debug assertion and warning bother you that much, you can disable them both.

Comment: I am working in the context of a cross-platform library, so I would have to demand that all applications disable the check. A better solution for me, is to add extra code that checks for the special case, but that is a nuisance, and it appears redundant to the reader. Not a huge problem, but a complication that should not have been necessary.

Comment: As each compiler is going to have their own flags to set, you'll have to have such a set for each compiler anyway.

Comment: Yes, but the fewer the better. Each additional constraint on applications is a problem.

Answer (score 0):

The C++11 standard states "[i,i) is an empty range" in 24.2.1/5.

However, in 24.2.1/5 it first implies that 0 must be a singular value and then states "Results of most expressions are undefined for singular values". It then lists exceptions to the undefined behaviour, but comparison is not included.

So maybe it's undefined to compare singular iterators for equality, hence making [i, i) impossible to evaluate.

This is also indicated by the fact that your runtime error happens inside a function named _Equal1().

I think the standard is vague with respect to this, and I'm not at all sure it's a bug in Visual Studio 2012.

http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-unresolved.html in the chapter "1213. Meaning of valid and singular iterator underspecified" is also pretty amusing with this confusion...